# Sum of Correlated Target Variables

Tags: python, random-forest, sum

I am using annual county-level data to predict a headline national figure that is the sum of the counties.

For this problem, I applied a Random Forest regression model to the county-level data to predict my scalar target for each county for the subsequent year. After meta-parameter tuning the model achieves $R^2$ in excess of 95% on the test set.

However, the errors aren't independent in any given year and subsequently the they often compound over the sum leading to a national prediction with a large error. Would greatly appreciate any idea on how to mitigate this compounding.